# Can we find more than one group such that $ G = G_1 \unrhd G_2 \unrhd G_3 \unrhd G_4 = \mathbb{Z} $?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

How do construct a group with a specified [lower central series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_series#Lower_central_series)?  Let's try the example where the series terminates at the [integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer):

$$ G = G_1 \unrhd G_2 \unrhd G_3  = \mathbb{Z} $$

What kind of number systems could these be?  Could these be [matrix-groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_group)?  Are they necessarily of the matrix type.

Here is one example already, [upper-triangular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix) matrices:

$$ \left[ \begin{array}{cccc}  1 & \mathbb{Z} & \mathbb{Z} & \mathbb{Z} \\ 0 & 1 & \mathbb{Z} & \mathbb{Z} \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & \mathbb{Z} \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{array} \right] $$

One possible source of algebra problems like this could be Dummit & Foote.  Or maybe on arXiv.

Basically, how many 3-step nilpotent groups are there?  We have commutator conditions $[G,G] = [G_1, G_1] \subseteq G_2$ and $[G_1, G_2] \subseteq G_3 = \mathbb{Z}$.

Example: $G = \mathbb{Z}^3 = \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ and then $[G, G] = \{ e\} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$.   This group is [commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_group).

We could try to construct group with generators $\{ e_1, e_2, e_3\}$ and give some kind of commutator relation of the elements $[e_i, e_j] = ...$ not sure how to do that.  Or how these match up with the matrix example.

---

Comments suggest the term "2-cocycle" learning what this term might mean.

- [Can we see directly from the cocycle condition that 2-cocycles are symmetric?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1329555/can-we-see-directly-from-the-cocycle-condition-that-2-cocycles-are-symmetric)
- https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/2-cocycle_for_a_group_action

Also discussion from Physics Page

- https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/16131/what-is-the-definition-of-a-2-cocycle-in-quantum-mechanics

Comment: Do you know how to construct central extensions from $2$-cocycles?

Comment: I am not really sure what you are asking. You have asked a lot of questions, but they sound more like general speculation rather than precise questions that would admit an answer.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan undergrad in abstract algebra might not know what "2-cocycle" is.  There's interesting note "2-cocycle of trivial group action" get's a separate page.

Comment: You can get further examples by taking a direct product of your example with any nilpotent group of class at most two.